# Getting Values From a Hashmap Randomly

Tags: java

So I have a hashmap of the the type `<T,Integer>`. T being a generic type.

T is the any object and integer is the amount of that object we current have in the map.

For example, a string "shirt" and has a value mapping to it of 3.

I would like to build a method called random that would return a random object from the map according to the current distribution of the objects.

Meaning, if I have 2 keys in my map.."Shirt" and "Pants". There are 3 "Shirts" in my map and 7 "Pants". The distribution should be 30% of the time it will be a shirt that gets returned and 70% of the time "Pants" will be returned.

How would I go about doing something like this with a random generator?

Comment: Could you please provide the source code you have at this point? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

That map data type is making it quite hard to implement your requirements. A better data structure will make it a lot easier. There are various possible data structures that optimise different things.

#### Solution for few distinct values / value counts

Here's a solution that works very well if you need to pick random values very often, and if you don't have too many distinct values / value counts:

How about a simple `List<T>` instead?

```
// Calculate this in advance
List<T> values = 
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .flatMap(entry -> Stream.generate(() -> entry.getKey())
                           .limit(entry.getValue()))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As per your example, this array will now contain 3 copies of `"Shirts"` and 7 copies of `"Pants"`

It's now very easy to pick a value at random with your desired probability distribution:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
T randomValue = values.get(random.nextInt(values.length));
```

Proof:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    result.compute(values.get(random.nextInt(values.length)), 
                  (s, j) -> j == null ? 1 : j + 1);

System.out.println(result);
```

... yields:

```
{Shirts=29955, Pants=70045}
```

Comment: Yes this true but my hashmap uses generic type. So it won't always necessarily be a string. It also the HashMap may have a size up to 100,000 or more objects. So making an array(Which I thought of before) would seem to be very inefficient.

Comment: @Coder_Moler10345: OK, I fixed the generics part. I'll leave the answer here in case someone finds this approach acceptable. I suggest you update your question with more specifics, otherwise you won't get the answer you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

If the map contains (virtually) 3 shirts and 7 pants, it means the map has an overall of 10 elements.

The probability to encounter a shirt is 3 / (7+3) = 0.3

The probability to encounter a pant is 7 / (7+3) = 0.7

Now, imagine you can roll a dice going from 0.0 to 1.0. If the dice shows a number between 0.0 and 0.3 -> pick a shirt. If the dice shows a number between 0.3 and 1.0 -> pick a pant.

The following code implements this idea:

```
private static <T> T randomBasedOnOcurrenceDistribution(Map<T, Integer> map) {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    double total = map.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
    double dice = random.nextDouble();
    double floor = 0.0;

    for (Entry<T, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        double currentProbability = entry.getValue() / total;
        if(dice < floor + currentProbability) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
        floor += currentProbability;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Unreachable");
}
```

Usage (copied from @Lukas answer):

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Shirt", 3);
map.put("Pant", 7); 

Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
       result.compute(randomBasedOnOcurrenceDistribution(map), 
                     (s, j) -> j == null ? 1 : j + 1);

System.out.println(result); //prints {Pant=69679, Shirt=30321}
```

Comment: What happens if two items have the same probability...For example, I now have 5 items  Shirt = 3, Pants = 4, Underwear = 3, Tanktop = 1, and socks = 6.

Comment: In this case there are two items with the same probability. So how do I make sure the items are weighted the same or have the same chance of being picked?

Comment: @Coder_Moler10345 If two items have the same probability, there is an equal chance that they are picked. Have you tried to run my code with more items ?